# Solve exp(x) = x

Tags: equation-solving

I need help to solve the function `Exp[x] = x`. I tried using `Solve` but I got an error that told me to use `Reduce` instead. I tried using `Reduce` and the output came out to be weird. The output came out to be : `C[1] \[Element] Integers && x == -ProductLog[C[1], -1]`. Is there another way to solve this so I would get a number value?

Comment: Try Plot[Exp[x] == x, {x, -2, 2}] and contemplate the result

Comment: `Last@Reduce[Exp[x] == x, x] /. C[1] -> 2 // N` and then replace `2` with any other integer.

Comment: The output of `Reduce[]` is saying that the equation has infinitely many *complex* solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Solve` and `Reduce` will only give you numbers, if the amount of solutions is finite. To have finitely many solutions, you could add this contraint

```
Reduce[{Exp[x] == x, Abs[x] < 15/10}, x]
(*2 solutions*)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why the constraint would make it have 2 results?

Comment: @Ccyan because if one solution in the complex numbers exists, then the complex-conjugate must be a solution too.

Comment: Why 2 results with that constraint? Look at output from: `Plot3D[{0, Abs[Exp[x + I y] - (x + I y)]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]`